# Email-to-Account / Standard / Custom Object

Tags: email, apex-email-service, emailtosalesforce

**Question:** What would be the right approach to setup an Email-to-Account (OR any other Email-to-Standard/Custom object) similar to the OOB Email-to-Case functionality?

**Use Case:** When an email is sent from a Standard/Custom object record and a user replies to the email, it is received on the same record. (Similar to how it works for a Case based on ref:_)

At the moment I see 2 ways: **Email-To-Salesforce** and **Apex Email Service**

1. **Email-to-Salesforce**: Links emails to Contact, Lead, Opportunity - However isnt very intuitive since

   - You need CC/BCC the Email-to-Salesforce address
   - Add the ref: Id to the Email manually
   - Emails land up in the 'Unresolved Emails' which need to be manually linked by the user later.
2. **Apex Email Service:** Requires custom development.

I've read a few posts with regards to this ([here](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iYxIQAU) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162961/need-to-ingest-email-to-a-custom-object)) and the answer seems to be more in the favour of Apex Email Service for **custom** objects. Would the same be applicable for other **standard** objects? Any advice from experience would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (Please edit your post). Email to case is a solution for a very specific workflow.

Comment: @identigral - Thanks. I've added the Use Case above. Let me know if it provides clarity.

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitation that would prevent you from using an Apex Email Service with the Account record.  The apex route is more flexible due to all the factors you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score -1):

The apex email-services can be a good approach both in the case of standard and custom objects. You just need to send JSON serialized object string to your email service in the email body and deserialize it in the email-service class and perform DML on deserialized sobject. You can find a nice description [here](https://sfdctiger.com/2020/10/salesforce-email-services/)

Comment: The link you shared does not work. Could you please reshare? Thanks!